# Live editing like jsFiddle or developer tools but to the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous, jsfiddle

I would like to implement a jsFiddle-like site but where others can see the changes being made to the page in real time.

What would be the best way to do this? If possible. I am doubtful I can get the changes made in things like web developer tools build into chrome for example and send them to the server and update the page with like socket.io. But is there any other open source service I could use to achieve this you know about?

Any tips would be awesome.

Comment: Look at http://ace.ajax.org/ and http://cloud9ide.com/

Answer (score 1):

Codepen.io is like JSFiddle, and has a collaborative "Pro" version for $9/month or $75/year. Check it out: http://codepen.io/pro/

The only other thing that comes to mind is http://beta.etherpad.org/ -- but it's just live collaboration for text editing. Not really like jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a serverside version like jsfiddle. For example you could write evil code that make damage to the service provider. I just imagine execute ddos attacks to others domain, writing infinty loops, load heavy stuff to the memory and so on.

But I still think it would be possible to create something own in a "trusted enviroment".

One of my colleague have tried this one: http://coderun.com/ but I dont know if there is some limitation that block the things that I talked about in the begining.

Comment: Cool thanks. I only want it to execute html/css/javascript except when they are changed it should send the change to the server so that it can update the page and send it back so that all users can see it.

Comment: Ok, whats wrong with using some desktop application, they often provide upload to FTP feature.

Comment: Well what I was hoping to do was have a webpage and make it editable by anyone and be able to see the changes in real time. I am taking a fine arts class and thought it would be cool to do for our project coming up to have a webpage that was essentially editable by anyone, and watch it change over time.